# Where do the zombies move in this quest?

Tags: zombicide-black-plague

My friends and I will soon play the Zombicide Black Plague Wulfsburg quests, starting with **Welcome to Wulfsburg**, which has the following setup:

[image: Map of the quest "Welcome to Wulfsburg"]

My question is the following. Where do the zombies that spawn in 5R move before the characters make their way through the houses of 1V, 5R and 8V ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found the solution. This is from the Zombicide Black Plague rulebook, page 24:

> In case there are no open paths to the noisiest Zone, Zombies move
>   toward it as if all doors were open, though locked doors still stop
>   them.

Which means the zombies from 5R will go stuck themselves in the dead-end of 8V until a character opens the door (which also allows another character to snipe them from the tower 10V in the meantime).